# Password in Dialog box

Tags: android, database, xampp

I am making an android app where i have to display the password which is randomly generated at the time of registration on a dialog box. I have added the alert dialog box but have no idea how to retrieve the the data from the database(XAMPP).

Comment: Welcome to so . Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what have you tried. please add snippet of code here.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ check this tutorial..

Comment: you need to connect your localhost IP with your android app , so any registration is done its directly comes to your database .